# How can I redirect inside helper class

Tags: php, magento

In Magento, I have a helper class data

```
class My_Advert_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
```

where

I have a function such as

```
    public function callValid($arrError){
.....
```

and in that function I am trying to redirect user to a certain login...

```
$this->_redirect($strReturnPath);
```

The setUrl is not redirecting. How can I redirect?.. **$strReturnPath** is getting */ as path. I need it to go to homepage
Receiving error like below

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method My_Advert_Helper_Data::_redirect() in
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set redirects within your helper class like the following

```
 Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($strReturnPath);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Yes you are right.. Though U am a bit wrong. the $strReturnPath has value */. Basically I want to return back to homepage. But doing the above I end up with hello/*/ if hello was the path I was in .

Comment: Is `Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*/'));` what you need?